# nginx reverse proxy based on response header

Tags: nginx, http-headers, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-upstreams

I have a setup of the website that powered by 2 web applications under the hood.

One application (`fast`) is supposed to handle catalog pages.
Another application (`slow`) is supposed to handle customer/cart/checkout pages.

Both applications should run on the same host:
example.com:80 (`fast`) and example.com:8000 (`slow`)
Of course, port 8000 is not exposed for the visitor and used internally by nginx.

I want that web requests reach `slow` application only if `fast` application returned specific response header, for example X-catalog-not-found.

The expected result is following:

1. all requests go to `fast` application example.com:80
2. if `fast` application found a product by uri - it renders the page
3. if `fast` application did not find a product by uri - it sends empty body and response header X-catalog-not-found
4. based on the header received in prev step, nginx performs proxy pass to `slow` application example.com:8000

I feel that ngx_http_proxy_module or/and nginx_upstream module should be used, but haven't found a working solution after reading the docs.

Comment: Is it an option to work with default http status codes like http 404?

Comment: For example, there are 2 urls:
example.com/running-short.html and example.com/cart

The fast application will find a product (by uri /running-short.html) and render it.

But it will not find a product by uri /cart and will send X-catalog-not-found header instead, which then should be handled by nginx and passed to the slow application

Comment: Yeah got that. There would be a simple solutions using error_page directive in case your application is able to send a http 404 status code as a response to the first request to the `fast`backend in case the product was not foud by uri. Would that work?

Comment: hm, sounds genius :) will try it.
I also want it transparently handle all HTTP requests, not just GET/HEAD

Comment: Is it working with the error_page? Can write an answer post about it